# Encode and decode in html audio player tag for #,& and + symbols

Tags: c#, audio, decode, urlencode, encodeuricomponent

I have an angular 6 application in which i have some html audio player sections. I have encoded `mp3` files via `encodeURIComponent` and used in `src` tag. Audio plays fine for below player

```html
<audio controls>
  <source src="www.test.com/api/downloadaudio?filename=test.mp3" type="audio/mp3">
</audio>
```

For special symbols like #, & and + it was encoded as per `encodeuricomponenet` and applied in source tag like below

File name - `Test#1.mp3`
File name - `Test&2.mp3`
File name - `Test+1.mp3`

```html
<audio controls>

  <source src="www.test.com/api/downloadaudio?filename=test%231.mp3" type="audio/mp3">

  <source src="www.test.com/api/downloadaudio?filename=test%262.mp3" type="audio/mp3">

   <source src="www.test.com/api/downloadaudio?filename=test%2B3.mp3" type="audio/mp3">
```

At the API side(C#) it was not properly decoded. I get the below value in C# side

For 1,2 and 3 case-> **test** was the value I got for file name instead of `test#1`,`test&2`,`test+3`

Let me know what am doing wrong here...

Thanks,

Selva

Comment: Can I have some comments ?

Comment: Can anyone share your comments on this? I need some attention on why this was happening?

Comment: Do you have the control of the API(c#) side? If you do, can you share the code part that does the HTML decoding?